# Fit Sidewaystable on single page with title

Tags: tables, appendices, rotating

I want to include a `sidewaystable` in my appendix. I want the title and the table to be on the same page. However, it won't stay on one page. I have tried using Minipage, but it didn't work. Also, I have tried rotatebox and adjustbox in different combinations.

I am using a template from my university.

```
\documentclass[liststotoc,bibtotoc,a4paper,12pt,parskip,final,draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage{rotating} %rotates images
\begin{document}
\appendix
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\chapter{Appendix}
\label{Appendix}
\section{Big Table One Page}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[!ht]
        \centering  
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{l|ccc|ccc|ccc|r|}
            \cline{2-10} 
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX)}} \\ \cline{2-10}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & \textbf{\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & \textbf{\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & \textbf{\%} \\ \hline 
            \rowcolor{LightCyan} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ 
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ 
            \rowcolor{LightCyan} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ 
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 0.00\% \\ 
            \rowcolor{LightCyan} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ 
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ 
            \rowcolor{LightCyan} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ 
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 &000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ 
            \rowcolor{LightCyan} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ 
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 0.00\% \\ 
            \rowcolor{LightCyan} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ 
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ 
            \rowcolor{LightCyan} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% & 000 & 000 & 000\% \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}

    \end{sidewaystable}

\frontmatter 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code complete, that we can copy it to our PC and compile. With title probably you mean section title. Where you like to have it? Also in landscape orientation? if not, than you cannot use `sidewaystable` but put table on `\rotatebox{90}{... table ...   }`.

Comment: From your picture of table follows, can be concluded, that table can't be fitted even i landscape page. You should consider to shrink its width first.

Comment: Hello ! I also already try rotatebox ! and  adjustbox ! I try different combinations but it didn't work

Comment: because your table is to huge! Make it narrower first!

Comment: how ? please explain, I am very new to latex.

Comment: from table image I see, that you have very wide column heads. Can you write in more lines? or use shorter text (abbreviation) and explain in table footnotes their meaning, etc. For more advice I need to see real table first.